# Navigation drawer for a short moment visible when I include perfect scrollbar

Tags: javascript, css, laravel, vue.js, scrollbar

I came up with a navigation drawer/tool-bar heavily inspired by vuetify. As I use Bootstrap-Vue I had to come up with something by myself. The code is used inside a Laravel application and it should be easily possible to reproduce this issue in a vue cli instance.

So basically it works as follows:

- If a mobile user opens the website, the drawer is hidden by default which is achieved through width/translateX. As **I did not want the navigation to be visible for a short moment, I made the drawer invisible by default**

  transform: translateX(-100%);

If we do not have a mobile user, the same attribute is set to 0%:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1260px) {
    .navigation-drawer {
        transform: translateX(0%);
    }
}
```

The tool-bar works as expected, so I leave it out.

I know decided to use perfect scroll in my navigation ( https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue2-perfect-scrollbar ) which also works as expected.

**However, if i wrap the component around my drawer it actually now is visible for a second or so and then the drawer is closed.** Seems like the transform/translateX attribute is being ignored.

Here is a shortender blade template (html) overview and the corresponding .js and .scss file:

**blade template**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- CSRF Token -->
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    <title>{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}</title>

    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>

    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Styles -->
    <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
        <div class="wrapper" id="app">

            <div class="overlay"
                :style="overlay"
                id='app-overlay'
            >
            </div><!--.overlay-->

            <nav
                class="navigation-drawer"
                :style="toggleDrawer"
            >
                <perfect-scrollbar>
                    <div class="sidebar--header">
                        <h3><a class="text-light text-decoration-none" href="#">Dashboard</a></h3>
                    </div>
                    <ul class="nav flex-column">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-light " href="#">Link 1</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-light " href="#">Link 2</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-light " href="#">Link 3</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-light " href="#">Link 4</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-light " href="#">Link 5</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-light " href="#">Link 6</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-light " href="#">Link 7</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-light " href="#">Link 8</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-light " href="#">Link 9</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-light " href="#">Link 10</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-light " href="#">Link 11</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </perfect-scrollbar>
            </nav><!-- navigation-drawer-->

            <nav
                class="tool-bar navbar navbar-light"
                :style="shiftArea"
            >
              <button
                type="button"
                @click="toggle = !toggle"
                class="btn btn-primary navigation-drawer--toggle"
              >
                Toggle Drawer
              </button>

              <ul class="nav text-primary from-inline">
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link btn btn-primary" href="#">Home</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </nav><!--.tool-bar-->

            <main
              class="content"
              :style="shiftArea"
            >
              <div class="container-fluid">
                // content
              </div>
            </main><!--.main-->
        </div><!--.wrapper-->
</body>
</html>
```

**app.js**

```
import PerfectScrollbar from 'vue2-perfect-scrollbar'

require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');
Vue.use(PerfectScrollbar)

Vue.component('example-component', require('./components/ExampleComponent.vue').default);

const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    loading: true,
    toggle: true,
    mobile: false,
    windowWidth: window.innerWidth,
  },
  computed: {
    toggleDrawer() {
      return this.toggle ? {'transform': 'translateX(0%)'} : {'transform': 'translateX(-100%)'}
    },
    shiftArea() {
      return (!this.mobile && this.toggle) ? {'padding-left': '266px'} : {'padding-left': '10px'}
    },
    overlay() {
      if (this.mobile && this.toggle) {
        return {
          'cursor': 'pointer',
          'z-index': 6,
          'opacity': 0.46,
          'background-color': '#212121',
          'border-color': '#212121'
        }
      } else {
        return {
          'cursor': 'pointer',
          'z-index': 0
        }
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    close(e) {
      if (e.target.id == 'app-overlay' && this.toggle) {
        this.toggle = false
      }
    },
  },
  watch: {
    windowWidth() {
      this.mobile = this.windowWidth < 1260
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    window.addEventListener('click', this.close)
    window.addEventListener('touchstart', this.close)

    window.onresize = () => {
      this.windowWidth = window.innerWidth
    }

    if (window.innerWidth < 1260) {
      this.mobile = true
      this.toggle = false
    }
  }
});
    },
  },
  watch: {
    windowWidth() {
      this.mobile = this.windowWidth < 1260
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    window.addEventListener('click', this.close)
    window.addEventListener('touchstart', this.close)

    window.onresize = () => {
      this.windowWidth = window.innerWidth
    }

    if (window.innerWidth < 1260) {
      this.mobile = true
      this.toggle = false
    }
  }
});
```

**...and app.scss**

```
// Fonts
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito');

// Variables
@import 'variables';

// Bootstrap
@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';

// Import Vue 2 Perfect Scrollbar
@import '~vue2-perfect-scrollbar/dist/vue2-perfect-scrollbar.css';

.ps {
    height: 100vh;
}

.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    min-height: 100vh;
    max-width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

.navigation-drawer {
    position: fixed;
    background-color: $primary;
    width: 256px;
    height: 100vh;
    z-index: 7;
    transform: translateX(-100%);
    transition-duration: .2s;
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.4,0,.2,1);
    will-change: transform;
    transition-property: transform,visibility,width;

    .active {
        color: $primary !important;
        background: #fff;
        border-right: 1px solid $secondary;
    }

    ul li a {
        padding: 1rem 1rem;
    }

    ul li a:hover {
        color: $primary !important;
        background: #fff;
        border-right: 1px solid $secondary;
    }
}

.sidebar--header {
    padding: 1rem;
}

.tool-bar {
    padding-left: 10px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #dee2e6 !important;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    height: 56px;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 5;
    transition-duration: .2s;
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.4,0,.2,1);
    will-change: transform;
    transition-property: padding;

    .navigation-drawer--toggle {
        margin-left: 10px;
    }
}

.content {
    padding: 66px 0px 36px 10px;
    background: #fff;
    display: flex;
    flex: 1 0 auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    transition-duration: .2s;
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.4,0,.2,1);
    will-change: transform;
    transition-property: padding;
}

.overlay {
    align-items: center;
    border-radius: inherit;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    transition: .3s cubic-bezier(.25,.8,.5,1),z-index 1ms;
    pointer-events: auto;
    color: #fff;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1260px) {
    .navigation-drawer {
        transform: translateX(0%);
    }
    .content {
        padding-left: 266px;
    }
    .tool-bar {
        padding-left: 266px;
    }
}

.ul--clean {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

**What I tried**

- wrapping the  tags instead of the  which produces the same
  result
- a lot of trail and error with the scss classes .ps and ps--active-y
- I even took out the vue2-perfect-scrollbar-css with the same result

I noticed that the component wraps the internal html in further html tags such as ps__rail-x and ps__rail-y. The height, width of these tags are updated as well (in px.). I believe that these tags somehow interfer with the other tags - I have, unfortunately, no clue how to fix the issue.

Unfortunately I couldn't upload this to a fiddle, as there is no cdn for perfect scroll.

What I am trying to achieve is that the drawer stays visible by default (as it does when I don't use perfect scroll).

**Edit**: I have been playing with the code, main changes are that I replaced transform with left css attributes and I also decided to apply css classes instead of styles.

For instance, if the user access through mobile, a css class "is--mobile" is added to the parent html tag which then decided what to do with the drawer and the rest of the page. I'll continue working on this, but I am a bit clueless why it works that way to be honest (while I dont mind to have found a solution that works).

temporary repository: https://github.com/rezaffm/drawer